# Problems while connecting to pandorbot server in android

Tags: java, android, pandorabots

I am trying to make a chatbot in android. So, I am trying to connect pandorabot with my android app.

```
public class Brain {
    public String defaultCustid = "0";
    public String custid = defaultCustid;
    public String responseFailed = "RESPONSE FAILED";
    public String defaultBotId = "da43c986ee34039e";
    public String defaultHost = "http://www.pandorabots.com";
    String botResponse;

    public String askPandorabots(String input) {
        return askPandorabots(input, defaultHost, defaultBotId);
    }
    public String askPandorabots(String input, String host, String botid) {
        String responseContent = pandorabotsRequest(input, host, botid);
        if (responseContent == null) 
            return responseFailed;
        else 
            return pandorabotsResponse(responseContent, host, botid);
    }

    public String pandorabotsRequest(String input, String host, String botid) {
        try {
            String spec = spec(host, botid, custid, input);
            return responseContent(spec);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public String spec(String host, String botid, String custid, String input) {
        String spec = "";
        try {
            if (custid.equals("0"))      // get custid on first transaction with Pandorabots
                spec =    String.format("%s?botid=%s&input=%s",
                        "http://" + host + "/pandora/talk-xml",
                        botid,
                        URLEncoder.encode(input, "UTF-8"));
            else spec =                 // re-use custid on each subsequent interaction
                    String.format("%s?botid=%s&custid=%s&input=%s",
                            "http://" + host + "/pandora/talk-xml",
                            botid,
                            custid,
                            URLEncoder.encode(input, "UTF-8"));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return spec;
    }

    public String responseContent(String url) throws Exception {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.setURI(new URI(url));
        InputStream is = client.execute(request).getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader inb = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
        String line;
        String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = inb.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line).append(NL);
        }
        inb.close();
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

This is the code I am using for the connection. But the bot always responds with "Response Failed".

```
String responseContent = pandorabotsRequest(input, host, botid);

if (responseContent == null) 
    return responseFailed;
else 
    return pandorabotsResponse(responseContent, host, botid);
```

Here, the value of responseContent becomes null, so "Response Failed" is being shown. I have looked through the quote several times but I can't seem to find why the value is null in responseContent. Can anyone more knowledgeable than me please look through the code and point out where I am making the mistake?

Comment: Does your logcat show any exceptions? Should be, for `pandorabotsRequest(String, String, String)` can only return null in the catch, `spec` and `responseContent(string)` cant return null, only throw the exception. Try to avoid catchalls (`catch (Exception e)`), but be specific

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, here is the fix:

Java is throwing an exception android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException deep in the HttpGet()

It is because you are trying to do a network operation on the main thread

add these two lines to your manifest.xml

add this import statement to your main activity

import android.os.StrictMode;

add these 2 lines of code to your main activity to the onCreate() method

StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

and you should be good to go!

Answer (score 0):

Make the HTTP request from a new **Thread**.

It should solve the **NetworkOnMainThreadException**.

Now to update anything in the **UI Thread** use **Handler**.

Answer (score -1):

Java is throwing an exception `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` deep in the `HttpGet()`

It is because you are trying to do a network operation on the main thread

add these two lines to your `manifest.xml`

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" 
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
```

add this import statement to your main activity

```
import android.os.StrictMode;
```

add these 2 lines of code to your main activity to the `onCreate()` method

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Comment: You have posted an almost identical answer twice.  I suggest you delete one of them.

Comment: This is a very bad solution.